# Laravel Eloquent Relationship without key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

How do I eager load another model in eloquent? The relationship isn't exactly a relationship in the traditional sense, it's a requirement.

I have a `users` table, and a `target_types` table. Every `user` will have all of the same `target_types`. So whatever `target_types` are present in the `target_types` table, will apply to all `users`. So there's no need for a foreign key type of relationship.

I realise I could go down the query builder route, however ideally I'd love to be able to do something like:

```php
User::with('target_types')->get();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just return a separated collection `target_types`, instead of forcing a non existing relation?

Comment: Could you give an example? Also, I'd love to be able to use nested eager loading, if I could get the above working

E.g. User::with('target_types.other_related_data')->get();

Comment: I mean, put into a different variable. `$users` will be the collection of users, `$targetTypes` the collection of target_types. Doesn't seems that you need this relation.

Answer (score 3):

As [Felippe Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580044/felippe-duarte) suggested, you could just return to your view/API both collections: `$users` and `$targetTypes`.

**app/Http/Controllers/SomeCoolController.php**

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // get your users
    $users = User::all();
    // get your target types
    $targetTypes = TargetType::all();


    // return them to your front-end
    return response([
        'data' => [
            'users' => $users,
            'target_types' => $targetTypes
        ]
    ], 200);

    // or in case you have a view
    // return view('my_cool_view', ['users' => $users, 'targetTypes' => $targetTypes]);

}
```

---

## Alternative

You say that the `targetTypes` will be the same for all users. In case this types doesn't change very often. Why not store them inside the model?

**app/User.php**

```php
public function getTargetTypesAttribute()
{
    return ['my', 'list', 'of, 'target', 'types'];
}
```

Then you could use it when querying for your users:

```php
$user = User::first();
dd($user->target_types);
// this will output the list of target types.
```

Comment: Sorry, a detail I missed was that I'm creating an API (not passing to a view) so the data would need to be present as JSON property when querying users.

Comment: @Steviewevie I've changed the return type in the controller and also included an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'fake' the relationship in the user model like this:

```
//in User model
public function targetTypes(){

    return TargetType::where("deleted_at", "<>", "NULL");

}
```

Then you can call it with the user in the controller like so:

```
User::with('targetTypes')->get();
```

Comment: That is why I said "you can fake it", haha

Comment: So, it is so because, the relationship returns an Eloquent collection on which you can call other Eloquent queries (e.g where()). The model has no idea, this is not a regular relationship.

Comment: I've just realised this doesn't work if the TargetType model has a different constraint, which in my case, it does.

Comment: What constraint is that?